# Write array values to file but with whitespace between each value

Tags: php, arrays

I want to write my array values to a file which i can do but the output ends up looking something like this:

> Thisisanexample

I basically want to split every array value up to look like this:

> This is an example

The array is what you would expect:

```
Array
(
[0] => This
[1] => is
[2] => an
[3] => example
)
```

I'm not sure how I could formulate this.

Comment: And how are you writing it to your file, exactly?

Comment: Please provide your code here...

Comment: if all you do is flat out concatenate the array values then that is exactly the result you will get. you would need to do something like `array[0] + " " + array[1] + " " + array[2].....`

Comment: You can use [`implode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) to get the string you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$array = ['This', 'is', 'example'];    
$stringToWrite = implode(' ', $array);
```

Comment: Works, Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If your data is small, you can use `implode()`.

```
fwrite($fp, implode(' ', $data));
```

Otherwise you would use a foreach and a little fiddling:

```
$lastValue = array_pop($data);
foreach ($data as $d) {
  fwrite($fp, $d);
  fwrite($fp, ' '); # or any other separator
}
fwrite($fp, ' ');
fwrite($fp, $lastValue);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to somthing like this...

```
  $write = array(
     '0' => 'This',
     '1' => 'is',
     '2' => 'an',
     '3' => 'example'
   );
   $stringToWrite = implode(' ', $write);
   fwrite($file, $stringToWrite);
```

Comment: Thank you, if only i could select multiple answers

Answer (score 1):

You could also use a `foreach()` loop and then concatenate the value with whitespace.

```
$array = ['This', 'is', 'an', 'example'];

foreach ($array as $v) {

    echo $v . " ";

}
```

**Output**

```
This is an example
```